# Lazy Loading recyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading

Does anyone know how to implement Lazy Loading recyclerView in android?I'm pretty new to android and I don't know how to figure this out.I'll be thankful if anyone helps.

Comment: it is pretty easy in Kotlin , just use lazy delegate

Comment: [Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews)?

Comment: cricket_007 link has been relocate https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Answer (score 9):

You may use EndlessRecyclerView

**Overview**
A common application feature is to load automatically more items as the user scrolls through the items (aka infinite scroll). This is done by triggering a request for more data once the user crosses a threshold of remaining items before they've hit the end.

The approaches for ListView, GridView and RecyclerView (the successor to ListView) are documented here. Both are similar in code except that the LayoutManager in the RecyclerView needs to be passed in to provide the necessary information to implement infinite scrolling.

In both cases, the information needed to implement the scrolling include determining the last visible item within the list and some type of threshold value to start fetching more data before the last item has been reached. This data can be used to decide when to load more data from an external source:
[To provide the appearance of endless scrolling, it's important to fetch data before the user gets to the end of the list. Adding a threshold value therefore helps anticipate the need to append more data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auteK.png)

**Implementing with ListView or GridView**
Every AdapterView (such as ListView and GridView) has support for binding to the OnScrollListener events which are triggered whenever a user scrolls through the collection. Using this system, we can define a basic EndlessScrollListener which supports most use cases by creating our own class that extends OnScrollListener:

```
import android.widget.AbsListView; 

public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
        {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) >= totalItemCount ) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

Notice that this is an abstract class, and that in order to use this, you must extend this base class and define the onLoadMore method to actually retrieve the new data. We can define now an anonymous class within any activity that extends EndlessScrollListener and bind that to the AdapterView. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ... the usual 
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        // Attach the listener to the AdapterView onCreate
        lvItems.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
              // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
              // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
              loadNextDataFromApi(page); 
              // or loadNextDataFromApi(totalItemsCount); 
              return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
          }
        });
    }


   // Append the next page of data into the adapter
   // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
   public void loadNextDataFromApi(int offset) {
      // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data 
      //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
      //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
      //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
      //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyDataSetChanged()`
   }
}
```

Now as you scroll, items will be automatically filling in because the onLoadMore method will be triggered once the user crosses the visibleThreshold. This approach works equally well for a GridView and the listener gives access to both the page as well as the totalItemsCount to support both pagination and offset based fetching.

**Implementing with RecyclerView**
We can use a similar approach with the RecyclerView by defining an interface EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener that requires an onLoadMore() method to be implemented. The LayoutManager, which is responsible in the RecyclerView for rendering where items should be positioned and manages scrolling, provides information about the current scroll position relative to the adapter. For this reason, we need to pass an instance of what LayoutManager is being used to collect the necessary information to ascertain when to load more data.
Implementing endless pagination for RecyclerView requires the following steps:
Implementing endless pagination for RecyclerView requires the following steps:
 1. Copy over the EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.java into your application.
 2. Call addOnScrollListener(...) on a RecyclerView to enable endless pagination. Pass in an instance of EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener and implement the onLoadMore which fires whenever a new page needs to be loaded to fill up the list.
 3.     Inside the aforementioned onLoadMore method, load additional items into the adapter either by sending out a network request or by loading from another source.

To start handling the scroll events for steps 2 and 3, we need to use the addOnScrollListener() method in our Activity or Fragment and pass in the instance of the EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener with the layout manager as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Store a member variable for the listener
    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Configure the RecyclerView
       RecyclerView rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
       LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       rvItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
       // Retain an instance so that you can call `resetState()` for fresh searches
       scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
           @Override
           public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
               // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
               // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
               loadNextDataFromApi(page);
           }
      };
      // Adds the scroll listener to RecyclerView
      rvItems.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
  }

  // Append the next page of data into the adapter
  // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
  public void loadNextDataFromApi(int offset) {
      // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data 
      //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
      //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
      //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
      //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyItemRangeInserted()`
  }
}
```

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Unreadable copy-paste... Better to just copy the link if you've nothing else to add ;)
Btw : +1 for good link, but -1 for copy-paste ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better because you don't need a specific version of minsdk

***step 1: create interface***

```
interface caller{
void call();
}
```

***step 2: create caller on your RecycleView***

***step 3: check is a last item? how ?***

***in you Recyclerview on onBindViewHolder***

```
if (position==items.size()-1){// its a last item
           callbacker.call();
}
```

***step 4: on your activity that create your recycler view  define and

     pass to your recycler view constructor***

```
callbacker call{
recyclerParamerList.addAll(ItemList items());
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```