# How to load data into recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want get some data from server and show into `recyclerView`. For application architecture i used **MVP**
I wrote below codes, but after loaded data from server, not show any data into `recyclerView`!

I used **debug mode** and show me data in this **break point**

```
public void add(List<DataItem> list) {
    list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but not show me data into `recyclerView`!

**My Activity codes :**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements ActiveTestsContract.View {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tester_active_tests, container, false);
        //Initialize
        init();
        //User token log
        if (!App.isEmptyString(App.getPrefs("JWT")) || !App.getPrefs("JWT").equals(ConstKeys.EMPTY)) {
            userToken = App.getPrefs("JWT");
        }
        //Load data
        getData();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTestsList(Data data, int page) {
        testerDashboard_emptyLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activeTests_pullToLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Get lasted page
        if (page == data.getLastPage()) {
            isHasLoadedAll = true;
            activeTests_pullToLoader.setComplete();
        }
        adapter.add(data.getData());
        //Complete items
        isLoading = false;
        nextPage = page + 1;
        activeTests_pullToLoader.setComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        context = getActivity();
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        testsPresenter = new ActiveTestsPresenter(this, 3);
        testerDashboard_loader = view.findViewById(R.id.testerDashboard_loader);
        activeTests_pullToLoader = view.findViewById(R.id.activeTests_pullToLoader);
        testerDashboard_emptyLay = view.findViewById(R.id.testerDashboard_emptyLay);
        emptyLayout_editProfileBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.emptyLayout_editProfileBtn);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView = activeTests_pullToLoader.getRecyclerView();
        //Adapter
        adapter = new TesterActiveRecyclerAdapter(activeModel, context);
        //Init recycler and adapter
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        activeTests_pullToLoader.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
    }

    private void getData() {
        activeTests_pullToLoader.isLoadMoreEnabled(true);
        activeTests_pullToLoader.setPullCallback(new PullCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                isLoading = true;
                //Call api
                testsPresenter.testsListResponse(App.recipesApi, userToken, nextPage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapter.clear();
                isHasLoadedAll = false;
                isLoading = true;
                //Call api
                testsPresenter.testsListResponse(App.recipesApi, userToken, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoading() {
                return isLoading;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasLoadedAllItems() {
                return isHasLoadedAll;
            }
        });
        activeTests_pullToLoader.initLoad();
    }
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class TesterActiveRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TesterActiveRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DataItem> list;
    private Context context;

    public TesterActiveRecyclerAdapter(List<DataItem> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_tester_test_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataItem item = list.get(position);
        //Name
        holder.txt_name.setText(item.getTitle());
        //Conditions
        if (!App.isEmptyString(item.getOs()) && !App.isEmptyString(item.getType()) && !App.isEmptyString(item.getBrowser())) {
            holder.txt_condition.setText(item.getType() + " | " + item.getOs() + " | " + item.getBrowser());
        }
        //Button actions
        holder.setState(item.getState(), position);
        //Price
        holder.rowTests_priceTxt.setText(item.getPrice() + " Dollar");
        //Animate items
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(App.context,
                (position > list.size() - 1) ? R.anim.down_from_top : R.anim.up_from_bottom);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);

        Toast.makeText(context, ""+list.get(0).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void add(List<DataItem> list) {
        list.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ViewGroup root;
        private TextView txt_name, txt_value, txt_condition, rowTests_priceTxt;
        private RoundTextView rowTests_button;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            root = (ViewGroup) view;
            txt_name = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTestListTitle);
            txt_value = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTestListSublist);
            txt_condition = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTestListSublist2);
            rowTests_priceTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.rowTests_priceTxt);
            rowTests_button = view.findViewById(R.id.rowTests_button);
        }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding data again in the same `list` passed in the parameter. Try to replace the below code

```
public void add(List<DataItem> list) {
    list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

with

```
public void add(List<DataItem> list) {
    this.list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thanks rahul, it's work me. but why not show data in my above code?

Comment: @Shambooli it didn't work because you were the very list that you were passing in the function and not the adapter's list.

Comment: I have written in my answer that you are adding the same list into the given argument list. If it helps don't forget to accept and upvote

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma, thanks. but can you send me your answer?

Comment: Yes I've added my answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57411329/8259771

Comment: @RahulKhurana, In your code, the order of displaying data will be corrupted after scrolling!

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear the current list
2. Add the data to the adapter's list.

   ```
   public void add(List<DataItem> list) {
       clear();
       this.list.addAll(list);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Your approach didn't work because you were updating the very list that you were passing in the function and not the adapter's list.

Comment: In your code, the order of displaying data will be corrupted after scrolling!

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: Can you send to me true code for lazy loader and pullToRefresh? each two feature into open sample!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454797/pull-to-refresh-recyclerview-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901697/lazy-loading-recyclerview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

First add all data into list & than notify your adapter , after this set your adapter to recyclerview.

```
list.addAll(data)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

  val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
  recyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
  recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager 
  recyclerview.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
  recyclerview.adapter = mAdapter
```